# How to prevent Hazelcast's MapStore from saving entries to often?

Tags: store, hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast (version 3.1.6) map with a map store configured this way:

```
    <map-store enabled="true">
        <class-name>com.mypackage.MapStore</class-name>
        <write-delay-seconds>60</write-delay-seconds>
    </map-store>
```

So I expected that entry will be stored ~once in 60 seconds (if it is being updated). But instead, if I update map entry, say, 10 times in quick succession, MapStore.store() will be called ~10 times too (but after 60 seconds). The most strange thing that it sometimes get called less than 10 times (but never one time as I want it to). Is there any way to change this behavior? I have a very write-intensive storage so these excessive store() calls create heavy load on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that isn't possible. Some customers need to have each update written to storage for auditing purposes. But I think it certainly is an interesting feature to have as a sort of 'write cache' to prevent hitting storage too often.

Can you create a ticket for it? I'll add the appropriate tags.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues

Once the 3.2 version release on done, we are going to focus a lot less on features, but will be shifting out attention to scalability and performance. Your feature falls nicely in those categories.

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/1864 added issue to github (sorry for my terrible english)

Comment: Your English is more than good enough :) And thanks for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can we provide access to the map's dirty entries as part of the solution. This way there will be more freedom to write any kind of writer for the map.